# Initial condition of 2nd order State-Space Representation (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, math, state-space

I want to calculate the initial condition `x0` of a sate-space representation of 2nd Order in order to use it in `lsim` command, using the initial system outputs (that I already have).

I know that an initial condition for 1st order looks like this: (sys includes the state-space vectors)

```
x0 = (y(1) - sys.d*u(1))*pinv(sys.c);
```

The problem for he second Order is that x0 is a vector `x0 = [x(1) x(2)]`. I have tried to solve it as an equation system but didn't get convinving results.

Ideas ?

Comment: You can not store two elements in one element: `X(k) = [x(k) ; x(k+1)]`

Comment: I used the 0 in V(0) so that you see that it's the initial condition. And yes my problem is that I can't store the elements in `X(k)`. I couldn't find another solution to calculate my `X(1)` depending on both equations.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your explaination, but if you're perhaps looking for a cell. `X{1} = [x(1) ; x(2)];` ?

Comment: Ben Jo, please reword your question. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @bremen_matt done :D

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the system is not observable. Please check that first.